# How to display song lyrics which is playing using MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am working on app that consists music player, I want to display song lyrics, currently I am using following code:

```
MPMediaItem *currentItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];
NSURL* songURL = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics];
AVAsset* songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:songURL options:nil];
NSString* lyrics = [songAsset lyrics];
```

Comment: And what's your question/issue?

Comment: this code not working

Comment: Did you check for each element if one of them were `nil`?

Comment: i checked,but not working

Comment: Well, that's normal. You do search for `MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics`, and it should returns an URL? You should instead look for `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL`. But could do: `NSLog(@"%@",[currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics]);`?

Comment: checked,but returns null

Comment: did you get the solution because I am facing the same issue that are you facing?